# Export current user location from locate control using button in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, export, select-by-location

I am preparing a mobile application, to determine the location of natural and cultural goods along a route that I have previously uploaded on Leaflet maps. I use the "leaflet locate control" plugin to establish my position and follow the route.

To capture the points of interest, and save them in a file along the route, I tried to use the code of TomazicM ([Export user location in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353959/export-user-location-in-leaflet)) to export lat and lng, but "mousedown" doesn't work so well on mobiles. It works perfect in the computer and sometimes in the mobil.

What I've tried to do is change the "mousedown" option to a button that performs the same function, but I haven't found the solution.

I want to use the button to save the coordinates of points of interest during a route. Just one point (my location) each time I press the button.
How can I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far but does not work:

```js
lc = L.control.locate({
    locateOptions: {
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
    showCompass: true,      
    maxZoom: 15,    
    strings: {
            title: "position ??"
    }}
}).addTo(map);
var cnt;
L.easyButton('far fa-save', function(btn, map) {
  map.on('locationfound', function (evt) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cnt = 0;     
      cnt++;
      if (cnt > 1) {
        cnt = 0;
        return;
      }

      saveAsLocalFile(JSON.stringify(evt.latlng), 'location.txt', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8');    
  }, 100);
});
}).addTo (map);

function saveAsLocalFile(data, filename, type) {
  var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
  else { // Others
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
    }, 0); 
  }
}
```

Comment: From your code (which cannot work) it's not clear what logic you have in mind. Please edit your question and explain the role of easy button. If it's constantly present on the map, how do you know when to press it? If you want it only to start location download then add it the map when location is found and remove it when location marker is removed from the map.

Comment: I want to use the button to save the coordinates of points of interest during a route. Just one point (my location) each time I press the button.

Comment: I'm using the plugging leaflet-locatecontrol: lc = L.control.locate({
 locateOptions: {
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
 showCompass: true,  
 maxZoom: 15, 
 strings: {
         title: "postion ??"
    }}
}).addTo(map);

Comment: Please edit the question and add additional info from your two comments in the body of the question. It's hard for somebody who wants to answer the question to go through all the comments to have clear picture of the question.

Comment: Sorry, although I have consulted many times the Stack Exchange pages is the first time I ask a question and I do not have very clear how to do it. I hope you can understand me now. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to reopen since question is not about actual save (which is not GIS related), but how to save location from current location gotten through Leaflet locate control plugin.

Comment: It would be great

Comment: @TomazicM Question has been reopened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If desired functionality is to save current location with save button when location is available from `L.control.locate` control, it makes sense to show save button only when `L.control.locate` is activated.

Activation of control and consequent retrieving of current location can be detected through standard map `locationfound` event. Problem is detecting deactivation of location control so that save button can be removed from the map, since there is no such native event neither in standard Leaflet neither in location control.

One way to detect locate control deactivation is to extend it, so that standard control's `stop` method also removes save button.

Relevant code could then look something like this:

```
var savedLatLng;

var easyButton = L.easyButton('fa-save', function(btn, map) {
   saveAsLocalFile(JSON.stringify(savedLatLng), 'location.txt', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8');
});

L.Control.MyLocate = L.Control.Locate.extend({
  stop: function () {
    easyButton.remove();
    L.Control.Locate.prototype.stop.call(this);
  }
});
L.control.myLocate = function (options) {
  return new L.Control.MyLocate(options);
};

lc = L.control.myLocate({
  strings: {
    title: "Show me where I am!"
  }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('locationfound', function (evt) {
  savedLatLng = evt.latlng;
  if (!map.hasLayer(easyButton)) {
    easyButton.addTo(map);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi TomazicM It seems to work perfectly.
I'm going to test it in the field and confirm it.
Thanks

Comment: If answer helped you solve your problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark answer as accepted to let other users know that problem was succesfuly resolved.

Comment: I've been testing it in the field and it works perfectly. It was just what I needed. Thanks